# Update 'this' from callback when returning function called with .apply()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a `ProjectClient` class that contains a method (`.GET()`) for making HTTP calls. It supports some arguments and a callback in the same manner as [node-request](/questions/tagged/node-request), but has some complex url and header building functions that happens behind the scenes too:

```
client.GET(idOrDataObject, function(err, customResponse) {
    // url is built based on the id or dataObject passed as the first param
})
```

On a successful response, one of the object types that comes back is a `DataObject`:

```
client.GET(idOrDataObject, function(err, customResponse) {
    console.log(customResponse.dataObject instanceof DataObject) // true
})
```

I'm adding a convenience method to the `DataObject` class called `reload()` that calls back to the `client.GET()` method and reloads itself, but I'd like to be able to update `this` with the new version of `DataObject` that's returned from the server:

```
DataObject.prototype.reload = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) // extracts all arguments
    var client = helpers.client.validate(args) // ensures 'client' was passed in the args array before continuing
    args.unshift(this) // prepends 'this' (the DataObject instance)

    // How can I update 'this' with the response contained in the 
    // callback passed (the last element in 'args')?
    return client.GET.apply(client, args)
}
```

Usage would look like this:

```
client.GET(idOrDataObject, function(err, customResponse) {
    var o = customResponse.dataObject
    // assume something changed on the server
    o.reload(function(err, done) {
         // o has now been updated with the latest copy from the server
    })
})
```

#### Update:

Starting to think the only way this will work is if I hijack the callback further down the chain, e.g. inside `client.GET`:

```
var DataObject = require('../lib/dataObject')
var request = require('request')
var _ = require('lodash')

var GET = function(client, args) {
    var options = {
        client: client
    }

    // if a preformatted options argument passed, assign it to options
    if (_.isObject(args[0]) && !_.isFunction(args[0]) && args.length <= 2) {
        _.assign(options, args[0])
    }

    options.callback = helpers.cb(_.last(args.filter(_.isFunction)))
    options.type = _.first([options.type, args[0]._type, args[0]].filter(_.isString))
    options.dataObject = _.first([options.dataObject, args[0]].filter(function(property) {
        return (property instanceof DataObject)
    }))

    request('http://...', {
        body: options.body,
        json: true,
        method: 'GET'
    }, function(error, response) {
        var customResponse = new CustomResponse(response)
        if (options.dataObject instanceof DataObject) {
            options.dataObject = customResponse.dataObject
            // here I see both 'options.dataObject' and 'customResponse.dataObject' have the correct value for reloadTest
            console.log('updated', options.dataObject.reloadTest, customResponse.dataObject.reloadTest)
        }
        options.callback(error, customResponse, customResponse.dataObject)
    })
}
```

But even doing this, the original copy of `dataObject` isn't being updated - it's as if it was cloned or duplicated and isn't a pointer to the original?

Here's a test that's proving the failure. How can I ensure that the correct pointer to `dataObject` is passed?

```
var now = Date.now()
client.GET('test', function(err, getResponse) {
    var dataObject = new DataObject(getResponse.dataObject)
    getResponse.dataObject.reloadTest = now // 1452109996140

    console.log('now', now, 'getResponse.dataObject.reloadTest', getResponse.dataObject.reloadTest)
    // now 1452109996140 getResponse.dataObject.reloadTest 1452109996140

    client.PUT(getResponse.dataObject, function(err, putResponse) {
        // updated 1452109996140 1452109996140

        console.log('putResponse.dataObject.reloadTest', putResponse.dataObject.reloadTest)
        // putResponse.dataObject.reloadTest 1452109996140

        dataObject.reload(function(err, response) {
            // updated 1452109996140 1452109996140

            console.log('done', dataObject.reloadTest, 'response.dataObject.reloadTest', response.dataObject.reloadTest)
            // done 1452109916111 response.dataobject.reloadTest 1452109996140
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: `reload` only takes one argument (a callback) that you've shown, so I'm unclear why you have several lines dealing `arguments`. What other arguments do you expect to be passed into `reload`?

Comment: don't unshift, then simply `return client.GET.apply(this, args)`

Comment: `reload` only takes one, but `GET` takes several. Rather than fight with what is or isn't there, I'm just passing args. Simple enough to get callback out of args though (using lodash, `_.last(args)`).

Comment: @dandavis have to unshift because client.GET takes dataObject as a first parameter. Updated my pseudo code for .GET to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't. You can't actually swap the object for another object. Some options:

- Use a wrapper object, and give that the `reload` method:

  ```
  client.GET(idOrDataObject, function(err, customResponse) {
      var o = new DataWrapper(customResponse);
      o.dataObject; // old data
      // assume something changed on the server
      o.reload(function(err, done) {
           o.dataObject; // new data
      });
  });
  ```
- Update the data in the `dataObject`, keeping the same object as before:

  ```
  DataObject.prototype.reload = function(callback) {
      client.GET(this, function(err, customResponse) {
          // Assign all properties from the response to the existing obj
          // Could also use $.extend, _.extend, etc
          Object.assign(this, customResponse.dataObject);
          callback(this);
      }.bind(this));
  }
  ```
- Just pass the new object in the callback and ignore the old object:

  ```
  DataObject.prototype.reload = function(callback) {
      client.GET(this, function(err, customResponse) {
          callback(customResponse.dataObject);
      });
  }
  ```

Comment: Have a look at my update - I think your second suggestion is on the right track, but since I'm already passing it down the chain, I'd like to see if I can get it working with the implementation I've already got?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how JS references work. You can change `options.dataObject`, but it's changing a property of `options` to point to a new object, not updating the old object. Unless your calling code is looking at `options`, it won't work. If you go the second route, you have to modify the object, *not* try to reassign the reference. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value/6605700#6605700

Comment: Ahh, yes you're completely right, I missed that entirely. Option 2 was definitely the simplest approach.